# Expected identifier image

Tags: xcode

Hi i am new here and also a noob with Xcode please help.
I am trying to make Imagepickercontroller but i am having trouble with one error and don't know how to solve it.

Viewcontroller.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {
IBOutlet UIButton *button;
IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
UIImagePickerController *imagepicker;

   }
    - (IBAction)change:(id)sender;

@end
```

Viewcontroller.m

```
 @interface ViewController ()


@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *mytouch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    button.center = [mytouch locationInView:self.view];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    imagepicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [imagepicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [imagepicker setAllowsEditing:YES];

}

- (IBAction)change:(id)sender
{
    [self presentViewController:imagepicker animated:YES completion:NO];

}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    [UIImage(setimage:)image];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NO];
}

@end
```

Expected identifier `[UIImage(setimage:)image];`

Answer (score 0):

[UIImage(setimage:)image] needs to be [someImageView setImage:image]
Where someImageView is an instance of UIImageView

Comment: tryed your code but it gives me a error that i need to change the someimageview to uiimageview

Answer (score 0):

Note that `UIImage` is a class, not a object. You should give a class method of `UIImage` without any parenthesis. 
In addition, `setImage:` is **not** a class method of `UIImage`. I guess, you mean a object instance, not the class object.

Comment: u mean like this: [UIImage setimage:image];?

Comment: No. `UIImage` is a **class** object, you need an **instance** object.